# Lightning Components in Site.com Studio - possible?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, site.com

I am searching far and wide, coming up with absolutely nothing giving me a straight answer...

I am looking to see if we can get Lightning Components in Site.com Studio (which we will use for a community).  Is this even possible?  Does it come in as a widget, asset, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to pull lightning components if you are in site.com studio mode.

You will use site.com studio to build your original templates or the pages and then switch over to the community builder to pull your lightning components to add to the site.com pages or community builder .

To assist you with same below is the screenshot to help you

The one is blue will help you to create site.com templates while one in Red will help you to drag lightning components to your site.com pages

[image]

[image]

To answer you in short it is definitely possible to use lightning components inside the site.com via community builder .